# Assembly x86 Win32

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64

I am trying to learn Assembly using x86 architecture. I can do basic calculations like add, sub, mul, imul, div, and idiv. However, when I attempt to print the result, there are several spaces in the string. Is there a way to remove these extra spaces? I am currently trying to remove them by looping through a string and sending the non-space characters to a second string. If this is the way to do this, why doesn't my code work? I read somewhere about exchange (xchg) but I am not entirely sure how to use it. Would this be a more efficient way?

```
              dtoa     product, eax      ; convert to ASCII characters
              dtoa     xStart, x
              dtoa     yContinue, y
              lea      edi, product
              mov      ecx, 20h          ; mov hex value of space into ecx

forStart:     cmp      [edi], ecx        ; compare edi to space
              jne      addToString
              add      edi, 4            ; get address of next array element
              cmp      [edi], 00h        ; cmp value of edi to null
              je       printResult
              jmp      forStart          ; loop through for next element

addToString:  mov      ecx, [edi]        ; mov value of edi into ecx
              add      edi, 4            ; get address of next array element
              cmp      [edi], 00h        ; cmp value of edi to null
              je       printResult
              jmp      forStart          ; loop through for next element

printResult:  output  resultLbl, xStart  ; output result
```

Answer (score -1):

This is quite incomplete. `dtoa` is not x86 instruction, so it's hard to tell what it does (probably some decimal to string conversion routine, but what exactly it does produce and how it works is mystery without it's source or proper documentation).

`product` declaration is missing, nor documented what it is.

And you don't define what is "string" for you either.

All of those are important, because then in code you do:

```
              mov      ecx, 20h          ; mov hex value of space into ecx
forStart:     cmp      [edi], ecx        ; compare edi to space
              jne      addToString
```

(BTW, you can write first one as `mov ecx,' '`)

`cmp [edi],ecx` will compare DWORD value with `' '`, so do you use UTF-32 encoding of strings? If you use classic ASCII encoding, then you have to compare BYTE only (`cmp [edi],cl`), and advance only by 1 (`add edi,1`).

`cmp      [edi], 00h` -> not clear value of what size is compared, use some size specifier, like `cmp      [edi], BYTE 00h` in NASM.

In `addToString` you fetch 4 bytes of string, but I don't see where you "add" it, so you do nothing there. Again using 4 byte elements would be valid with UTF-32 encoding, but somehow I suspect you are using ASCII zero-terminated strings, so you should work with bytes instead?

Most of this can be figured out in debugger, if you step instruction by instruction, and take notion how values in registers change, and watch memory content trough memory view at interesting addresses (where `edi` points to during scan for `' '`, etc). And confront that with instruction reference guide, making sure you understand how each instruction works exactly.

So this question shows lack of effort (debugging) + asking for debugging.

And finally about your question(s) itself:

Your code does work exactly as you wrote it, ie. completely unrelated to your original intention of "sending non-space characters to second string", the code is not even close to it.

Why you wrote unrelated code .. hard to say, probably you should try to break your original intent even a bit more into simpler sub-task (in comments in English), and keep those around when you implement the simple sub-steps with instructions, so you can during debug compare what is happening in CPU with your original intent.

`xchg` swaps two values. Certainly it's possible to use such instruction even for string manipulation, if you understand how strings are stored in memory, and what value you want to swap with which other value (depends what is your intent).

Would there be a more efficient way?

Hard to tell, I'm not even sure what you want to achieve. If it's like "current output: `____30`" (_ is space), "wanted output: `30`", then you actually don't need to modify the string, you just should count the initial space characters, and give "output" subroutine the `xStart + <space_count>` address, so it will not encounter the bytes containing spaces. Or maybe there's some configuration for `dtoa` or there's some other function in your library working like C `printf`, where you can specify exact formatting easily.

---

edit: "hard to tell" emphasis:

And the comments you keep in code are often useless, or even wrong.

```
addToString:  mov      ecx, [edi]        ; mov value of edi into ecx
```

First, it doesn't move value of `edi` into `ecx`, but value of memory content pointed to by address in `edi`, which is fatal difference.

Second, you state the obvious, that's what that instruction does. You should rather archive your "human intent" in comment, ie:

```
addToString:  mov      ecx, [edi]        ; reading 4 ASCII letters of string into ecx
```

If you would do that, it would be easier to point out, where your human intentions goes off when compared to the implementation in instructions, and point your mind-level mistakes to you.

As is, it's possible only to write the working code instead of you, but whether you would understand why it is so different and how it works... So it would require lot of effort on your side (to understand it) to truly help you. And you show lack of effort in question - no point to provide working example.